# Можно ли так сравнивать объект класса?

Tags: c++

```
void f( MyClass obj ){
    if( obj ){
    }
}
```

В моменте `if( obj )` хотелось бы чтобы вызывался какой-то перегруженный оператор, или ещё что.
Реально ли сделать подобное?

Comment: если вы хотите, чтобы в этом месте вызывался оператор класса, то вызывайте нужный вам оператор класса

Comment: Ну, если он у вас приводится к `bool`, то пуркуа бы и не па?...

Comment: мне лень писать `if( obj.valid() )...` вот и спрашиваю

Answer (score 2):

Вкратце - если у вас есть оператор приведения к `bool` (или чего-то, что приводится к `bool`, и без неоднозначностей), то [можно](https://ideone.com/uIjesc).

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(int x = 0):val_(x){ cout << "Test(" << x << ")\n"; }
    ~Test()           { cout << "~Test(" << val_ <<")\n"; }

    operator int() const { cout << "Test::operator int(" << val_ <<")\n"; return val_; }
    operator bool() const { cout << "Test::operator bool(" << val_ <<")\n"; return val_; }

private:
    int val_ = 0;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test t(5);
    if (t)
    {
        cout << "true\n";
    }
}
```

Можете выкинуть оператор `bool` и посмотреть на результат.